# Inheritance using a function as the base object constructor

Tags: python, oop

I've imported a package that provides me with a class and a wrapper function that creates an instance of that class. 
For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def print_a(self):
        print(self.a)

    def print_b(self):
        print(self.b)


def makeFoo(x, y):
    a = x + y
    b = x - y
    return Foo(a, b)
```

I want to have a similar class `NamedFoo`, that has the same properties/methods, also has a name property, and with a constructor that calls `makeFoo`. I figure that this should be solved using inheritance, with `NamedFoo` being a subclass of `Foo`. However, I don't know how to make the `NamedFoo` constructor utilize `makeFoo` correctly:

```
class NamedFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, x, y, name):
        # ???
        # Foo = makeFoo(x, y)   ??
        # self.Foo = makeFoo(x, y)  ??
        self.name = name

    def printName(self):
        print(self.name)
```

Example data:

```
myNamedFoo = NamedFoo(2,5,"first")
myNamedFoo.print_a()  # (From makeFoo: a = x + y) ==> 2 + 5 = 7
myNamedFoo.print_b()  # (From makeFoo: a = x - y) ==> 2 - 5 = -3
```

I'm not too familiar with object-oriented programming, so I might just be using the wrong search terms, but I haven't found anything similar to what I need. Is this possible, and if so how can I do it?

I'm also not sure if this is an X/Y problem, but here are the alternatives I've considered and why I don't think they're ideal:

- Composition of `Foo` and the property `name`: It's ugly and doesn't seem right.
- Manually adding the `name` property to each `Foo` object, and perhaps wrapping it in a function: Doesn't quite have the elegance of a one liner constructor.
- Rewriting the constructor for the `Foo` class, to have the same code as what's in `makeFoo`: `makeFoo` is rather complex and needs to do a lot of setup, and this would in any case lead to code duplication

Comment: Generally you wouldn't ever do this unless you wanted to hide the fact that you were using a class as an implementation detail, and since python doesn't use the `new` keyword to instantiate classes the line is pretty blurry from a user's perspective anyway. That logic in makeFoo should *probably* be in the constructor of a subclass that you would then subclass again to get your NamedFoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `NamedFoo` constructor, create an instance of the `Foo` class from the `makeFoo` wrapper function. Pass this instance's attributes to the `super().__init__`.

```
class NamedFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, x, y, name):
        _foo = makeFoo(x,y) # use the wrapper to handle complex logic from input params
        super().__init__(_foo.a,_foo.b) # pass the properly derived Foo attributes to the superclass constructor
        self.name = name
```

This way, we're instantiating `NamedFoo` from whatever magic happens within the `makeFoo` function. Pass your `x` and `y` to that, which creates a throwaway `Foo` instance (so we can have it properly constructed with whatever complex logic resides in the helper function). The final `NamedFoo` class is then instantiated from the `Foo` constructor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work..

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a + b
        self.b = a - b

    def print_a(self):
        print(self.a)

    def print_b(self):
        print(self.b)


class NamedFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self,a,b,name):
        super().__init__(a,b)
        self.name = name


def main():
    example = NamedFoo(2,5,"first")
    example.print_a()
    example.print_b()

main()
```

this prints out

```
7
-3
```

or if you really want to use a function to create self.a and self.b use this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = make_foo(a,b)

    def print_a(self):
        print(self.a)

    def print_b(self):
        print(self.b)


class NamedFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, a,b,name):
        super().__init__(a,b)
        self.name = name


def make_foo(x,y):
    return x+y, x-y

def main():
    example = NamedFoo(2,5,"first")
    example.print_a()
    example.print_b()

main()
```

Comment: No, I need the constructor to be based on makeFoo, not the constructor of Foo. I've added some sample data to make it clearer.

Comment: The problem is that Foo and makeFoo are provided by a package, and the logic behind them is rather complex and I'd rather not need to go too deep into the implementation and change the source code of the package itself.